# Return a text string if no values found

Tags: javascript, string, return-value

I am displaying a google map if latitude and longitude values for a camera object are found. (These values are fetched with ruby.)

I have got it so that if longitude values aren't found the map is not displayed (1st line) but I can't get the text string to appear.

```
function initialize() {
    if (cameraLong === '') return;

    var cameraLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(cameraLong, cameraLat);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: cameraLatlng
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: cameraLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Camera Location'
    });

    var mapFirstClick = false;
    $("#nav-tabs").click(function() {
        mapFirstClick || setTimeout(function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            mapFirstClick = true;
            map.setCenter(cameraLatlng);
        }, 200);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: the one we cant see !

Comment: Hi, yea the line `if (cameraLong === '') return;` makes sure the map doesn't load in a random location if no values are found. What I need then is a text string that says no values are found instead of loading nothing!

Comment: It is unclear what should happen with your text string. Here is an idea: `if (cameraLong === '') return "The coordinates weren't found.";`, so just return the string?

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do and what I expected to happen if I did what you did above but for some reason the string is not displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to something to appear, you have to write code to do it. For example:

```
if (cameraLong === '') {
    $('#map-canvas').replaceWith("<p>The coordinates weren't found.</p>");
    return;
}
```